# Is there an alternative to a large $or query in MongoDB / mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Imagine I have a large collection in MongoDB, like

```
{
  filename: 'a.jpg',
  filepath: '/images/83920/',
  ...
},
{
  filename: 'b.jpg',
  filepath: '/images/52345/',
  ...
},
{
  filename: 'c.jpg',
  filepath: '/images/14152/',
  ...
},
...
{
  filename: 'xyz.jpg',
  filepath: '/images/15325/',
  ...
}
```

Now I want to retrieve multiple documents at once, where each documents matches a specific criteria.

Right now i am doing it like:

```
db.getCollection('images')
    .find({
        $or: [
            {filename: 'b.jpg', filepath: '/images/52345/'},
            ...
            {filename: 'xyz.jpg', filepath: '/images/15325/'},
        ]
     });
```

My question is: Is there an alternative to a large $or query in MongoDB / mongoose?

Something like

```
db.getCollection('images')
    .findMultiple([
            {filename: 'b.jpg', filepath: '/images/52345/'},
            ...
            {filename: 'xyz.jpg', filepath: '/images/15325/'},
    ]);
```

would be really helpful.

Or is the $or chaining the intended way to do it?

Comment: What don’t you like about using `$or`?

Comment: Besides syntax, can you please share more about what you are trying to achieve? Are you hitting a performance or request size limitation using `$or`?

Comment: What does the ellipsis mean in the example? Select all files with the same path that are lexicographically between the two that are listed?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a derived field for query purposes:

```
{
  filename: 'a.jpg',
  filepath: '/images/83920/',
  hash: md5(filename, filepath),
  ...
},
```

Then query for `$in(hash)`.

This will allow you to index the hash field.